# css or javascript add a :hover style to complete line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a PRE tag with a bunch of code in it and several lines. I want to apply a :hover style when a user hovers over a line.

Is there a way I could do this using CSS or Javascript? I looked at :first-line and couldn't find anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `<span class="changeonhover">` tag around each line and then you can have that effect.

Answer (score 0):

pre tags are good way of dumping an array. Its not the best way to display the actual array or data.

If you want to do it in CSS:
wrap it around a div

```
.prediv a:hover{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

And use:

```
<div class="prediv"><a href="#"><pre>CONTENT</pre></a></div>
```

This would hover the whole content not line by line.
My suggestion is use ul li tags and do a for loop in JavaScript and dump lines into li.

Hope this helps.